# Replace values in array using mask and other array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, indexing

I have a 1D "from"-array (call it **"*frm*"**) containing values with an associated Boolean mask-array: **"*mask*"** (same shape as ***frm***). Then I have a third "replace" array: **"*repl*"**, also 1D but shorter in length than the other two.

With these, I would like to generate a new array (**"*to*"**) which contains the ***frm*** values *except* where *mask==True* in which case it should take **in-order** the values from ***repl***. (Note that the number of *True* elements in ***mask*** equals the length of ***repl***).

I was looking for a "clever" numpy way of implementing this? I looked at methods like *np.where*, *np.take*, *np.select*, *np.choose* but none seem to "fit the bill"?

"Cutting to the code", here's what I have thus far. It works fine but doesn't seem "Numpythonic"? (or even Pythonic for that matter)

```
frm  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mask = [False, True, False, True, True]
repl = [200, 400, 500]
i = 0; to = []
for f,m in zip(frm,mask):
    if m:
        to.append(repl[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        to.append(f)
print(to)
```

Yields: `[1, 200, 3, 400, 500]`

(*Background*: the reason I need to do this is because I'm subclassing Pandas *pd.Dataframe* class and need a "setter" for the Columns/Index. As *pd.Index* cannot be "sliced indexed" I need to first copy the index/column array, replace some of the elements in the copy based on the mask and then have the *setter* set the complete new value. Let me know if anyone would know a more elegant solution to this).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `numpy` solution:

Its pretty straightforward like this:

```
# convert frm to a numpy array:
frm = np.array(frm)
# create a copy of frm so you don't modify original array:
to = frm.copy()

# mask to, and insert your replacement values:
to[mask] = repl
```

Then `to` returns:

```
>>> to
array([  1, 200,   3, 400, 500])
```

## `pandas` solution:

if your dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df
   column
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
```

Then you can use `loc`:

```
df.loc[mask,'column'] = repl
```

Then your dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df
   column
0       1
1     200
2       3
3     400
4     500
```

Comment: Re the numpy solution: Nice! Here I am looking for "special methods" completely overlooking the fact that I can simply assign to a variable using the mask for the indexing! :-)

Comment: Re the Pandas solution: I'm aware using _"loc"_ for this for the *contents* of a DataFrame. As I can tell, there's no equivalent for the Axes (the "index" and "column" names, not the actual values _inside_ the dataframe).

For example: ``df.columns[3]`` works. But ``df.columns[3] = "new-name"`` gives ``TypeError: "Index does not support mutable operations"`` (which prompted me to take it into numpy for the solution).

Comment: Oh I guess I misunderstood what you were going for... yeah it's probably best to do it in numpy and use the resulting array as your index (IIUC)